# admin-ajax and external service interaction

Tags: wp-admin

we recently had a penetration test performed against our WordPress sites. the highest vulnerability is due to /dashboard/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php being able to take payload and thus acting as a proxy. Is there any way to stop this from happening? The pen test folks mentioned setting some sort of ACL but I understand this particular page needs to be accessible to admins for the site.

I'm not a WordPress guy so I'm not familiar with the platform.

edit:

I came across this security fix but I'm not sure if it's related to our issue. Another thing related to this issue was that they were able to do a DNS lookup via the same endpoint. Their screenshot shows the response to an A record lookup.

https://wpvulndb.com/vulnerabilities/9912

The pen test folks were able to use our WP install as a proxy utilizing a Burp Collaborator. The parameter they show is the content variable. What they explained to me was that they were able to submit a URL via content in the URL I mentioned above and it went through via this URL.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! A bit more of detail (in an [edit]) might help to shed some lights. Also: While you can throw a bunch of things at "the default AJAX endpoint", it doesn't mean it will get through. There are nonces and other things in place to prevent piercing through it. So this endpoint isn't any more or less vulnerable than any other endpoint. In fact, it isn't even available from everywhere.

Comment: Also there's the modern REST API, but what you've shared is... vague, can you be more specific? What do they mean by payload? `admin-ajax.php` fires hooks and so the security of the file is dependent on the security of your theme and plugins. If `admin-ajax.php` can act as a proxy then that's not standard WP behaviour, you're going to have to give technical details, it's unavoidable

Comment: edit my post. not sure if that's enough. I'm not too familiar with this stuff.